# Правильно ли говорить "В жизнях других людей"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить "В жизнях других людей"? Или нужно говорить "в жизни"?

Answer (score 4):

Это один из случаев, когда применение общих правил (здесь: согласования по числу) к построению речи может приводить к не вполне естественным выражениям (часто этим грешат переводы). Носители языка обычно говорят так: "в жизн**и** других людей (такое случалось)", "их жизн**и** угрожала опасность", "спасти им жизн**ь**" и т. п., хотя в некоторых контекстах (реинкарнация, 9 жизней у кошки и пр.) употребляется множественное число. Лучше всего такие выражения усваивать целиком из хороших текстов.

**P.S.** Видимо, надо пояснить, как здесь работает единственное число. *В жизни [**каждого** из этих] других* людей то, о чём говорится, происходит по-своему, индивидуально. Подспудное понимание неповторимости человеческой жизни препятствует здесь употреблению множественного числа слова "жизнь" (одного, другого и т. д. - людей много, но *жизнь* у каждого своя, "другая"). В подобных случаях подразумевается *жизнь **каждого*** из тех, о ком говорится (спасти им жизн**ь** = спасти жизнь *каждому* их них).

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю, что стилистически верно: **в жизни других людей.**

Это видно из статистики в Нацкорпусе: **в жизни/в жизнях, 30000/25.**

Дело в том, что жизнь — это нечто индивидуальное, и было бы странно объединять несколько жизней в одно понятие.

Хотя существительное ***жизнь*** имеет форму множественного числа, но естественными могут быть такие фразы: у нас не несколько жизней, а только одна; их жизни пересеклись, соединились.

Но даже в этом случае (соединив свои судьбы)  каждый человек живет **собственной жизнью**, и поэтому мы говорим: **в их жизни (в жизни каждого из них)** произошли существенные изменения.

Тем не менее можно встретить такие варианты: Какие изменения **в жизнях и судьбе** могли бы тут возникнуть! [Сергей Есин. Марбург (2005)]

Я думаю, что их следует отнести **к стилистической неточности**.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с тем, что "в жизнях других людей" звучит непривычно, так не принято говорить. Думаю, дело в том, что слово *жизнь* во многих контекстах воспринимается носителями языка как неисчисляемое существительное. Одновременно с этим предполагается, что все понимают, что каждый проживает эту жизнь отдельно. Думаю, здесь главным аргументом служит "так принято".